# MySQL DATETIME type inputs

Tags: mysql

In MySQL table, why datetime type take inputs in Y-m-d H:i:s format?

Why can' it accepts inputs in d-m-Y H:i:s format?

Comment: That's how it is... =) God's will maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on server variables.

Run this query to see them -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'date%format';
```

Have a look at the manual about date_format and datetime_format options.

Comment: The variable date_format and the variable datetime_format in MySQL do nothing and have historically never done anything. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format

Comment: @Isotopp Yes, indeed, these variables for some reason are unused by server; just readonly

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 format for dates. This is an international standard. It is also the only date format used by MySQL.

This format has the added advantage that is sorts correctly in a natural way, as the order YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is nicely ordered from less to more specific.

You can use the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format function to format that kind of date into any desired form, or you are doing this client-side using functions of your host language.

Answer (score 0):

This is mysql standard to accept the date. You have to pass it in the specified format.

There should be an standard to accept and store the date internally mysql chosen `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Think if there is no standard how mysql internally determine what format the date is stored in database and how proceed with dates.

Your are sending date in `dd-mm-yyy` `02-02-2011` other people is sending `mm-dd-yyyy` `02-03-2011`. If there is no standard for date format it is impossible to determine the month and date in above example.

Mysql chosen it to be `YYYY-mm-dd`